# How to fix invalid memory access on dll calback call from java?

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I have a separate thread, which is calling a method from DLL in a while/call/sleep loop, which on it's turn calls mapped callback from my java app. The first call of `cabinet.ProcessCallbacks.apply()` is successful, but all subsequent calls fail with `java.lang.Error: Invalid Memory Access`, which is very odd. Do you have any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

```
private void registerCallbacksCycle(final int rate) {
    Thread buttonsCycle = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Refreshing Callbacks ...");
                try {
                    System.out.println("       ");
                    byte b = cabinet.ProcessCallbacks.apply();
                    System.out.println("result " + b);
                } catch(Error e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            System.out.println("Refreshing Callbacks END ...");
            sleep(rate);
            System.out.println("Refreshing Callbacks AFTER SLEEP ...");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println("Refreshing Callbacks EXCEPTION ");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    };
    buttonsCycle.start();

    System.out.println("Callback Cycles started successfully ... ");
}
```

[**UPDATE**]
Java mapped to DLL:

```
public class OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1 extends Structure {
    /** C type : Initialize_callback* */
    public OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1.Initialize_callback Initialize;
    /** C type : ProcessCallbacks_callback* */
    public OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1.ProcessCallbacks_callback ProcessCallbacks;
    /** C type : Shutdown_callback* */
    public OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1.Shutdown_callback Shutdown;
    /** C type : SetButtonCallback_callback* */
    public OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1.SetButtonCallback_callback SetButtonCallback;
    /** C type : SetLights_callback* */
    public OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1.SetLights_callback SetLights;
    public interface Initialize_callback extends Callback {
        byte apply();
    };
    public interface ProcessCallbacks_callback extends Callback {
        byte apply();
    };
    public interface Shutdown_callback extends Callback {
        void apply();
    };
    public interface SetButtonCallback_callback extends Callback {
        void apply(ButtonCallback cb, Pointer userData);
    };
    public interface SetLights_callback extends Callback {
        void apply(int lights);
    };
    public OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1() {
        super();
    }
    protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("Initialize", "ProcessCallbacks", "Shutdown", "SetButtonCallback", "SetLights");
    }
    /**
     * @param Initialize C type : Initialize_callback*<br>
     * @param ProcessCallbacks C type : ProcessCallbacks_callback*<br>
     * @param Shutdown C type : Shutdown_callback*<br>
     * @param SetButtonCallback C type : SetButtonCallback_callback*<br>
     * @param SetLights C type : SetLights_callback*
     */
    public OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1(OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1.Initialize_callback Initialize, OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1.ProcessCallbacks_callback ProcessCallbacks, OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1.Shutdown_callback Shutdown, OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1.SetButtonCallback_callback SetButtonCallback, OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1.SetLights_callback SetLights) {
        super();
        this.Initialize = Initialize;
        this.ProcessCallbacks = ProcessCallbacks;
        this.Shutdown = Shutdown;
        this.SetButtonCallback = SetButtonCallback;
        this.SetLights = SetLights;
    }
    public OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1(Pointer peer) {
        super(peer);
        read();
    }
    public static class ByReference extends OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1 implements Structure.ByReference {

    };
    public static class ByValue extends OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1 implements Structure.ByValue {

    };
}
```

It seems that this is happening only when i make calls to the DLL from separate threads. Event `Native.synchronizedLibrary` doesn't help.

[**UPDATE 2**]

```
public class IKernel {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IKernel.class);

    private static final String OGAPI_DLL = "ogapiDLL_Release";
    private static final String ADMIN_V = "admin_v1";
    private static final String LEGION_CORE_V = "legion_core_v1";
    private static final String DEBUG_V = "debug_v1";
    private static final String CABINET_V = "cabinet_buttons_v1";

    private static Object HANDLE = new Object();
    public static String CONTENT_ID = "999406";
    public static Integer LOG_LEVEL = 3;
    public static Integer CALLBACK_REFRESH_RATE = 2000;

    protected static IKernel kernel;

    private OGAPI_Admin_Interface_v1 admin;
    private OGAPI_LegionCore_Interface_v1 core;
    private OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1 cabinet;

    public static IKernel instance() {
        if (kernel == null) {
            synchronized (HANDLE) {
                kernel = new IKernel(CONTENT_ID, LOG_LEVEL, CALLBACK_REFRESH_RATE);
            }
        }

        return kernel;
    }

    protected IKernel(String contentId, int logLevel, int rate) {

        initialize(contentId, logLevel);

        registerCallbacksCycle();
    }

    private void initialize(String contentId, int logLevel) {
        logger.info("OGAPI Initialization started ...");

        OGAPILibrary ogapi = (OGAPILibrary) Native
            .synchronizedLibrary((OGAPILibrary) Native.loadLibrary(
                    OGAPI_DLL, OGAPILibrary.class));
        admin = ogapi.RequestAdminInterface(ADMIN_V);

        OGAPI_Admin_Interface_v1.RequestInterface_callback request = admin.RequestInterface;

        Pointer coreIntPointer = request.apply(LEGION_CORE_V);
        core = new OGAPI_LegionCore_Interface_v1(coreIntPointer);

        Pointer debugIntPointer = request.apply(DEBUG_V);
        OGAPI_Debug_Interface_v1 debug = new OGAPI_Debug_Interface_v1(debugIntPointer);

        if (contentId != null) {
            debug.SetContentID.apply(contentId);
        }

        admin.SetLoggingCallback.apply(new LoggingCallback() {
            public void apply(Pointer userData, String msg, int level) {
                logger.info("Remote Logger: " + msg);
            }
        }, null);
        admin.SetLoggingLevel.apply(logLevel);

        Pointer cabinetIntPointer = request.apply(CABINET_V);
        cabinet = new OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1(cabinetIntPointer);

        boolean success = admin.Initialize.apply() == 1
            && cabinet.Initialize.apply() == 1;
        if (!success) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ikernel initialization failed");
        }
        logger.info("OGAPI Initialization completed successfully ...");
    }

    private void registerCallbacksCycle() {
        Thread buttonsCycle = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        logger.info("Refreshing Callbacks ...");
                        try {
                            logger.info("       ");
                            byte b = cabinet.ProcessCallbacks.apply();
                            logger.info("result " + b);
                        } catch (Error e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        logger.info("Refreshing Callbacks END ...");
                        sleep(CALLBACK_REFRESH_RATE);
                        logger.info("Refreshing Callbacks AFTER SLEEP ...");
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        logger.info("Refreshing Callbacks EXCEPTION ");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        buttonsCycle.start();

        logger.info("Callback Cycles started successfully ... ");
    }
}
```

Header for the CabinetInterface method:

```
typedef void (__cdecl *ButtonCallback )( void* userData, int buttonIndex, int pressed );

typedef struct tag_OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1 {

    bool (__cdecl *Initialize)();
    bool (__cdecl *ProcessCallbacks)();
    void (__cdecl *Shutdown)();
    void (__cdecl *SetButtonCallback)( ButtonCallback cb, void* userData );
    void (__cdecl *SetLights)( unsigned int lights );

} OGAPI_CabinetButtons_Interface_v1;
```

Comment: Are you sure your thread keeps running after registerCallbacksCycle returns?

Comment: You need to provide a bit more detail around what it means to register your callbacks and what your library mapping (both Java and native) looks like.

Comment: I made few tests and i observe that if i registerCallbacksCycle doesn't do while loop in separate thread but in the same thread everything is working as expected, but then it blocks the thread forever and i need this to be background process.

Comment: I also tried to use Native.synchronizedLibrary, but the result is the same...

Comment: I am thinking this Native.synchronizedLibrary is not working because i have callbacks registered, so the DLL is calling my methods unsafely. Could this be the issue?

Comment: `Native.synchronizedLibrary` only prevents concurrent access from multiple threads, it doesn't resolve any issues your library might have when accessed from multiple threads.

Comment: Show code where you implement and register the callbacks, as well as initialize the structure that I'm assuming you're using to register the callbacks.  If your structure's callback fields are uninitialized, that might cause your native code to fail.  Run with `Native.setProtected(true)`, and ensure your DLL is not expecting stdcall calling convention (if it is, you need to derive from `StdCallCallback` and your library from `StdCallLibrary`).  Show your native header definitions for structure/callback as well.

Comment: I updated the question with the headers and the whole java class which wraps the dll. JNA protected is true by default. Again, i want to note that calls from the same thread work fine, but if i put the ProcessCallbacks method in background thread it is not working. Is it correct to call native methods from different threads at all?

Comment: Is it possible that the GC f*cks up something?

Comment: Whether or not your native library can handle operating on different threads depends on that library.  Some do, some don't.  The only way GC would affect your callbacks is if you don't keep a reference to them; GC will dispose of them and the native callback handling will find a null function pointer (which should result in a JNA warning on the console, but not a crash unless the native caller is depending on a callback return value or operational result).

Comment: Oh, BTW, `Native.synchronized()` will have no effect on explicit native function pointer invocations (e.g. `ProcessCallbacks.apply()`).  You'll need to implement your own single-threading support for those.

Comment: You can synchronize around your `.apply()` calls on the object returned by `NativeLibrary.getInstance()`; that is the object used by `Native.synchronizedLibrary()`.

Comment: Great that worked, but now the native library doesn't call the callbacks implemented in my java code. For example the logger callback registered in the initialize() method doesn't get called:
 admin.SetLoggingCallback.apply(new LoggingCallback() {
            public void apply(Pointer userData, String msg, int level) {
                logger.info("Remote Logger: " + msg);
            }
        }, null);

Comment: Have you checked if different heaps are used by your js and your java code? I had the same problem with js-ctypes and a c++ dll and the problem was diffrent heaps -> callback cant be used

Comment: HoW could i check this?